# Convert uniqueidentifier type to string

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

In my database SQL Express 2014 ,

I have table named `Membership`  with column named `UserId`.The column type is `uniqueidentifier`.

I want to convert the content of the UserId column to string, for this purpose I use this row:

```
select convert(nvarchar(50), UserId) as UserId from Membership
```

But after I execute the row above I still get the set of numbers and letters in a `uniqueidentifier` format.

**Updated:**

Here the example of the data in the table in column UserId:

```
3CDDF65A-3F2B-48C9-814B-006AB2B70B5A
```

I need to cast it to string.

Any idea what I do wrong?How can I convert and display `uniqueidentifier` fomat in string?

Comment: So what is your expected output?

Comment: Can you show some sample data

Comment: `SELECT CONVERT(char(255), UserId) AS 'UserIdStr';` ?

Comment: @TheGameiswar can you see please update

Comment: `select convert(nvarchar(255),replace('3CDDF65A-3F2B-48C9-814B-006AB2B70B5A','-',''))`

Comment: what exactly do you want to get from a `uniqueidentifier`?

Comment: @qxg I expect to get some readable text value

Comment: If so, just select other columns, like names. It's quite common that a table only contains _non-readable_ content.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That is the NewID() GUID
As unique as it gets in your DB

If you wanted a more readable Id you should have used INT/BigInt as a primary key with Identity(1,1) as your UserID

All of these return exactly the same thing

```
DECLARE @User_ID UNIQUEIDENTIFIER = NEWID()
SELECT CAST(@User_ID AS NVARCHAR(50))
SELECT CONVERT(NVARCHAR(50),@User_ID)
SELECT @User_ID
```

unique_identifier is exactly that, a unique identifier, not some kind of encrypted value of a common string or int

Comment: so there is no way to convert it to something more readable because it generated by DB?

Comment: @Michael uniqueidentifier isn't some sort of secret hashing. That's the actual value in there. The string would be exactly the same. Why would you want something more readable? Identities are an option, as mentioned above.

Comment: Any reason not to use char(36)? n seems like overkill since guid is limited to a-f,0-9 and dash characters, and it's not variable in size.

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty sure that your code `SELECT CONVERT(nvarchar(50), NEWID()) AS UserId` actually convert uniqueidentifier to string.

If you are looking for another answer, you should specify the result which you expect from the conversion.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the SQL I would use:

```
DECLARE @Value1 uniqueidentifier
PRINT 'Value1: ' + ISNULL(convert(nvarchar(100), @Value1), 'NULL')

DECLARE @Value2 uniqueidentifier
SET @Value2 = newid()
PRINT 'Value2: ' + ISNULL(convert(nvarchar(100), @Value2), 'NULL')
```

This makes sure that if the values are NULL, something *will* get displayed, so the output would be this:

```
Value1: NULL
Value2: 9D630D0F-53B3-4A7B-93C2-E0B6F4C398F6
```

You might, or might not, want this extra functionality.